# Справка в боковой панели перекрывает футер

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, дизайн

При прокрутке страницы задания вопроса вниз справка в боковой панели перекрывает нижнюю часть страницы со ссылками на сайты сети:

> [image: панель перекрывает футер]

Comment: мож на мету стоит перенести

Comment: В упор не вижу, где там баг то?

Comment: Плавающие справочные панели - похоже на by design.

Comment: [Об эффективных багрепортах](http://egorfine.com/ru/articles/effective-bugreports/)

Answer (score 3):

> Мы считаем, что информация в боковой панели крайне важна, как результат, она всегда видна. В то же время, нижняя часть сайта не имеет такой важности, а при желании на все ссылки можно использовать прокрутив страницу немного вверх.

[@Pops](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/)

Comment: Можно же просто останавливать скролл при достижении кромки футера. Очень криво сейчас выглядит.

Comment: @Vadizar Как вы правильно заметили, технической сложности в реализации нет. Текущий подход основан именно на идеи важности информации в боковой панели.

Comment: Если человек крутит скролл аж в самый низ, то ему **важно** в этот момент именно подвал, а не боковая панель. Поэтому правильнее останавливать панель перед подвалом, как было замечено @Vadizar