# Навигация справки по Markdown отображается некорректно

Tags: дефект, поддержка, дизайн

Навигация в [cправке по Markdown](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) при пролистывании до конца страницы налезает на футер. Скорее всего, такого быть не должно.

---

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> Указанная выше информация уже получила ответ на вопрос ***[здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3461/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80)***
> **[статус-так-задумано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be)**

Однако, если [выбрать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#headers) один из пунктов навигации, в содержимом появляется описание, то блок уходит за границы браузерного окна (на мониторах с разрешением 1366x768 навигация почти полностью скрывается за границей окна):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такого уж точно не должно быть

Аналогичная проблема и на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-lists)

Причина возникновения проблемы:

```
position: fixed;
```